# PHP looping with mysql Showing the same username 5 times, instead of all usernames

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a foreach loop to show all of the usernames from my database.
When I run the loop I get, '10' is the rank.

> Daniel 10
>   Daniel 10
>   Daniel 10
>   Daniel 10
>   Daniel 10

This is the loop that I have

```
<?php
    include_once 'dbconfig.php';

    if(!$user->is_loggedin())
    {
        $user->redirect('index.php');
    }

    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users ");
    $stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));
    $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<h1>Players</h1> 
<table> 
    <tr> 

        <th>Battletag</th> 
        <th>Preferred Role</th>
        <th>Rank</th> 
    </tr> 

        </tr> 
        <?php var_dump($row)?>

        <?php foreach($userRow as $row): ?> 
                     <td> <?php print($row['user_name']); ?></td>
                     <td> <?php print($row['user_rank']); ?></td>
                 </tr>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    <a href="home.php">Home</a>


</table>
```

I don't see why it is looping the 1 user 5 times, instead of looping through all users once

Comment: Your foreach loop is $userRow as $row, so in the loop you should reference $row, not $userRow. This doesn't seem right though, because it seems $userRow is not a multidimensional array?

Comment: Have you tried a SELECT * query?

Comment: Could you add you SQL in too? As @Tristan notes, it doesn't seems like `$userRow` is a multidimensional array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK 3 things. First, you don't need parameter binding in

```
$stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));
```

so, instead of that, use:

```
stmt->execute();
```

Next, instead of `fetch`, use `fetchAll` function. You need this in order to get all rows for your query from database, instead of only first one.

And finally, in the loop the problem is that you are using `$userRow` instead of `$row` inside for loop. Try:

```
<?php foreach($userRow as $row): ?> 
    <td> <?=$row['user_name']?></td>
    <td> <?=$row['user_rank']?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: When I vardump $row i'm getting null, why is that?

Comment: Actually, can you show more code? How do you get value of `$userRow`?

Comment: Added my entire players.php page

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work for you.  It's not a for each loop though.  If you're set on using a for each loop then disregard.

```
$sql = "SELECT user_name, user_rank, 
    FROM XXX//your database//";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

//Display results

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo '<table>
           <tr>
               <th>User Name</th>
               <th>User Rank</th>
           </tr>';

     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr>
                   <td>" . $row["user_name"]. "</td>
                   <td>" . $row["user_rank"]. "</td>
               </tr>";

     }
     echo "</table>";

} else {
     $message = "0 results";}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sparta.  I fat fingered that too quickly.

Comment: This is the error that is coming up after implimenting this
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

I have added my database name in the sql, do I need to change anything else?